# Wordpress media_handle_sideload() function for a particular url

Tags: wordpress

I am importing around 9,000 images to wordpress using media_handle_sideload() library. One particular URL is giving 500 internal error... Spent around 10 hours to find out this particular image URL. Rest of the images are OK. I tried renaming but no use.

> http://cbproads.com/cbbanners/TBS830043971538.jpg

Comment: Turn on debug in config

Comment: Have you tried from your desk this URL? I tried debug, but only 500 internal error by the server. I am on BLUEHOST shared server.

Comment: http://cbproads.com/cbbanners/TBS830043971538.jpg working from browser very fine. It does not work from media_handle_sideload() function...

Comment: OK so what is different compared to other urls?

Comment: Other 9000 image url works and downloaded successfully. Can any do a debug with this image url?